# file streaming from Android to WCF

Tags: android, wcf

I have the following contract:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "Upload")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Upload/{step}/{fileName}",
            BodyStyle= WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        Response FileUpload(string fileName, string step, Stream fileStream);
```

And the implementation:

```
public Response FileUpload(string fileName, string step, Stream fileStream)
        {
            FileStream fileToUpload = new FileStream("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Upload\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

            byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000];
            int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            } while (bytesRead > 0);

            fileToUpload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
            fileToUpload.Close();
            fileToUpload.Dispose();

            Response res = new Response();
            res.Successful = true;
            res.Comment = "Bla bla";
            return res;
        }
```

And configuration:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="StreamHTTP"
                contract="BillboardServices.IBillboardService"
      />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamedHTTP"
                 transferMode="StreamedRequest"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000"
                 maxBufferSize="1000"
                 />

      </webHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I call the method through Android http request, I get status code 400 - Bad Request.
I have other methods on the same web service, which are working.
I just can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Use Wireshark to examine the *actual* wire traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried it on both the Android side and the Server side and it just looks like a normal multi-part post. I'm not a big networking wiz, but it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup a test server, based on the code you have posted above.

I executed the following using Fiddler...

POST http://localhost:3333/upload/step/filename HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Fiddler

Host: localhost:3333

Content-Length: 11

```
<Foo></Foo>
```

And on the server I tweaked your code a bit to something like this...

```
 public string FileUpload(string fileName, string step, Stream fileStream)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        return "Done";
    }
```

I had no issues.The code ran fine.

Are you sure the URI template you have used is not getting conflicted with some other endpoint perhaps? (usually WebGet)

Comment: Well I created a new project. This time I used the WCF ajax service instead of the WCF service application and everything works now. You were the only one to reply, so... Have fun :)